# (incorrect order of items in category column)Write an SQL query to produce a ranked listing of the top-5 categories

Tags: postgresql

Write an SQL query to produce a ranked listing of the top-5 categories according to how many films are associated with each category. The query's result must have the following columns:

rank - the ranking of the Category;
category - the name of the Category; and
films - the number of films belonging to the Category.
The results should be ordered primarily by rank in increasing order, then alphabetically by name (for any categories which have the same ranking).

I wonder how to let the output have correct order.

```
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(film_id) DESC),name as 
Category,count(film_id) as films
FROM Category
NATURAL JOIN Film NATURAL JOIN Film_Category
group by name
LIMIT 5
```

expected:

```
+------+-----------+-------+
| rank | category  | films |
+------+-----------+-------+
|    1 | Horror    |     9 |
|    2 | Action    |     4 |
|    2 | Foreign   |     4 |
|    2 | New       |     4 |
|    5 | Animation |     3 |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

actual:

```
| rank | category  | films |
+------+-----------+-------+
|    1 | Horror    |     9 |
|    2 | New       |     4 |
|    2 | Action    |     4 |
|    2 | Foreign   |     4 |
|    5 | Animation |     3 |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following before the `LIMIT` clause to get the order you want:

```
ORDER BY rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(film_id) DESC),
         name
```